# Jsoup is not replacing document content

Tags: java, jsoup

Here I am storing html content in `mailFormat.getBody()` now inside mail format I want to replace `span#userName`'s text with specified name stored in `(String) res.get("name")` and `span#password`'s text with `getPassword()`.
Line `System.out.println(usrName + "  " + passwd+" "+mailFormat.getBody());` is showing replaced userName and passwd but it is not updating at `mailFormat.getBody()`.
My code snippet is below.

Jsoup is not updating at base document `mailFormat.getBody()`

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(mailFormat.getBody());
 Elements elms = doc.select("span#userName");
 Element usrName = doc.select("span#userName").first();
 System.out.println((String) res.get("name") + " " + getPassword() + " el " + usrName);
 usrName.text((String) res.get("name"));
 Element passwd = doc.select("span#password").first();
 passwd.text((String) getPassword());
 System.out.println(usrName + "  " + passwd+" "+mailFormat.getBody());
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML?

Comment: Your code only replace `doc`. You should push it back to `mailFormat`.

Comment: Yes resolved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029):

> Your code only replace `doc`. You should push it back to `mailFormat`.